# Tutorials for installing PCL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm a new user for PCL and I got an error during installation.
I was trying to use the CMAKE GUI 3.15.2 to generate visual studio 2013 WIN64 files. But it throws an error. I use this video to install PCL :
[dideo](https://www.dideo.ir/v/yt/hgboDlKHl4c)

but when I use CMake I got this:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable PCL_ROOT is set to:

    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Found eigen: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Eigen/eigen3  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Found Boost: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/include/boost-1_61 (found suitable version "1.61.0", minimum required is "1.40.0") found components:  system filesystem thread date_time iostreams serialization chrono atomic regex 
Could NOT find openni (missing: OPENNI_LIBRARY OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to openni will be disabled
Found OpenNI2: C:/Program Files/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib  
Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
Could NOT find RSSDK (missing: _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to rssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
Found Flann: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib  
Could NOT find openni (missing: OPENNI_LIBRARY OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni will be disabled
Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to ensenso will be disabled
Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to davidSDK will be disabled
Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to dssdk will be disabled
Could NOT find RSSDK (missing: _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to rssdk will be disabled
Found qhull: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib  
looking for PCL_COMMON
Found PCL_COMMON: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_common_release.lib  
looking for PCL_OCTREE
Found PCL_OCTREE: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_octree_release.lib  
looking for PCL_IO
Found PCL_IO: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_io_release.lib  
looking for PCL_KDTREE
Found PCL_KDTREE: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_kdtree_release.lib  
looking for PCL_SEARCH
Found PCL_SEARCH: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_search_release.lib  
looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_sample_consensus_release.lib  
looking for PCL_FILTERS
Found PCL_FILTERS: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_filters_release.lib  
looking for PCL_2D
Found PCL_2D: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/include/pcl-1.8  
looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
Found PCL_GEOMETRY: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/include/pcl-1.8  
looking for PCL_FEATURES
Found PCL_FEATURES: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_features_release.lib  
looking for PCL_ML
Found PCL_ML: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_ml_release.lib  
looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_segmentation_release.lib  
looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_visualization_release.lib  
looking for PCL_SURFACE
Found PCL_SURFACE: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_surface_release.lib  
looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
Found PCL_REGISTRATION: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_registration_release.lib  
looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
Found PCL_KEYPOINTS: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_keypoints_release.lib  
looking for PCL_TRACKING
Found PCL_TRACKING: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_tracking_release.lib  
looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
Found PCL_RECOGNITION: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_recognition_release.lib  
looking for PCL_STEREO
Found PCL_STEREO: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_stereo_release.lib  
looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
Found PCL_OUTOFCORE: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_outofcore_release.lib  
looking for PCL_PEOPLE
Found PCL_PEOPLE: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_people_release.lib  
Found PCL: optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_common_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_common_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_octree_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_octree_debug.lib;C:/Program Files/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib;vtkalglib;vtkChartsCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersCore;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingCore;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkfreetype;vtkzlib;vtkDICOMParser;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOXML;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOCore;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkexpat;vtkexoIIc;vtkNetCDF;vtkNetCDF_cxx;vtkhdf5_hl;vtkhdf5;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkParallelCore;vtkIOLegacy;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersVerdict;verdict;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkIOImage;vtkmetaio;vtkjpeg;vtkpng;vtktiff;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;vtkgl2ps;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingStencil;vtkInteractionImage;vtkIOAMR;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOExodus;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingGL2PS;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL;vtkRenderingOpenGL;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkIOImport;vtkIOInfovis;vtklibxml2;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOMINC;vtkIOMovie;vtkoggtheora;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOParallel;vtkjsoncpp;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkIOPLY;vtkIOSQL;vtksqlite;vtkIOVideo;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLIC;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsInfovis;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_io_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_io_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s-gd.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_kdtree_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_kdtree_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_search_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_search_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_sample_consensus_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_sample_consensus_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_filters_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_filters_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_features_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_features_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_ml_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_ml_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_segmentation_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_segmentation_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_visualization_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_visualization_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic_d.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_surface_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_surface_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_registration_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_registration_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_keypoints_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_keypoints_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_tracking_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_tracking_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_recognition_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_recognition_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_stereo_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_stereo_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_outofcore_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_outofcore_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_people_release.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/lib/pcl_people_debug.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_61.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic_d.lib;C:/Program Files/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib;optimized;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s-gd.lib;vtkalglib;vtkChartsCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersCore;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingCore;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkfreetype;vtkzlib;vtkDICOMParser;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOXML;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOCore;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkexpat;vtkexoIIc;vtkNetCDF;vtkNetCDF_cxx;vtkhdf5_hl;vtkhdf5;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkParallelCore;vtkIOLegacy;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersVerdict;verdict;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkIOImage;vtkmetaio;vtkjpeg;vtkpng;vtktiff;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;vtkgl2ps;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingStencil;vtkInteractionImage;vtkIOAMR;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOExodus;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingGL2PS;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL;vtkRenderingOpenGL;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkIOImport;vtkIOInfovis;vtklibxml2;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOMINC;vtkIOMovie;vtkoggtheora;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOParallel;vtkjsoncpp;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkIOPLY;vtkIOSQL;vtksqlite;vtkIOVideo;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLIC;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsInfovis (Required is at least version "1.2") 
Configuring done
```

> I want to know what's the reason for the mentioned warning on CMake?
>   can anyone help me to run it completely?

Comment: Do you need any of those features that have been disabled? If so , hunt down and install the libraries that provide them.

Comment: @user4581301 yes I need all these libs. PCL include these libs but they don't install.

Comment: You'll need to install then manually